# Need help understanding proving linear independency of polynomial vectors and combinations using Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I had this specific question where I had to prove vectors $p1 = t^2 + 4t − 3$, $p2 = 2t^2 − 3t$ and $p3 = t + 1$ are linearly independent in $P_{2}(t)$ and also express $t^2 + 4t − 3$ as a linear combination of vectors $p1$, $p2$ and $p3$.

[My_Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFauP.png)

After putting the equations into matrix with basis {$1$,$t$,$t^2$}, why are they considered as linearly independent just by the rank of the matrix formed where the coefficients of the equations are columns of the matrix. Is it necessary to reduce it to row echelon form?

Also why does putting the matrix in Ax=b resulting in values of coefficients of p1,p2,p3 work? Is there any way to verify the solution I get?

Comment: To verify your solution compute the linear combination you got at the end and check that it equals the wanted polynomial.

Comment: @Al.G. It does equal the wanted polynomial but I don't know if this approach is right or not. Should I try to row reduce the matrix formed by using equations as columns everytime or it's fine without doing that?

Comment: First, yes, you should reduce the matrix to a row-echelon form, otherwise you wouldn't know that the vectors are independent :). Second, I don't think you're asked the right question, because a vector $p_1$ is always expressible as a linear combination of $p_1,p_2,p_3$, just by taking $p_1=1\cdot p_1+0\cdot p_2+0\cdot p_3$, no matter what $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are (that's just saying $a=a+0+0$, which is trivial). It seems there should be another polynomial in the question for expressing, can you check if it's really $p_1$ again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After putting the equations into matrix with basis {1,t,t2}, why are they considered as linearly independent just by the rank of the matrix formed where the coefficients of the equations are columns of the matrix. Is it necessary to reduce it to row echelon form?

I encourage you, at least initially, to *not* follow such "prepared recipes" for solving standard linear algebra problems, especially if you're interested to know why every step is done. Instead, work your way out by hand:

1. You're asked to find if $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are linearly independent. They would be dependent if you could express (at least) one of them, $p_i$, in terms of the others: $p_i=\sum_{j\neq i}\lambda_j p_j$ for some $\{\lambda_j\}_{j\neq i}$.
   Rearranging, that means that for at least one $i$ you could write $0=\sum_j \lambda_j p_j$ for some coefficients $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ where $\lambda_i=-1$ (the coefficient in front of $p_i$).
   This implies that you could write $\sum_j \lambda_j p_j=0$ for some $\lambda_j$ not all zeros. and is actually equivalent to the above (why?).
2. Hence you're asked if $\sum_j \lambda_j p_j=0$ could be written with at least one non-zero $\lambda_i$.
3. Note now that this is a vector equation - on the left we have a linear combination of the vectors $p_i$, on the right we have the zero vector. In finite dimensions we can always expand vectors in a base, which in your case looks like this: $$\lambda_{1}\begin{pmatrix}-3\\
   4\\
   1
   \end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\
   -3\\
   2
   \end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\
   1\\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
   0\\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}.$$ You know that multiplication with scalars and addition works component-wise, so performing them in each row, we get $$\begin{pmatrix}-3\cdot\lambda_{1}+0\cdot\lambda_{2}+1\cdot\lambda_{3}\\
   4\cdot\lambda_{1}-3\cdot\lambda_{2}+1\cdot\lambda_{3}\\
   1\cdot\lambda_{1}+2\cdot\lambda_{2}+0\cdot\lambda_{3}
   \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
   0\\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}$$ which is precisely a linear system of equations (the rows)!
4. Now recall the original question - do there exist $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, at least one non-zero, for which this equation is satisfied? If yes, then the vectors $p_i$ are dependent, if no non-zero solution exists - they're independent. Also note that you *don't need* the particular solution, but only to know if one exists.

---

> Also why does putting the matrix in Ax=b resulting in values of coefficients of p1,p2,p3 work? Is there any way to verify the solution I get?

Note that you can answer this question -- how to express a vector $v$ in terms of a set of other vectors -- the same way, but instead of the zero vector on the right-hand side like above, you'll have $v$.

1. You're asked if $v$ is a combination of the $p_i$s, that is, if $\sum_j \lambda_j p_j = v$ for some coefficients $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.
2. Note now like before that this is a vector equation - on the left we have a linear combination of the vectors $p_i$, on the right we have the vector $v$. In finite dimensions we can always expand vectors in a base, which in your case looks like this: $$\lambda_{1}\begin{pmatrix}-3\\
   4\\
   1
   \end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\
   -3\\
   2
   \end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\
   1\\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}=v.$$
3. Performing the sums component-wise, you get $$\begin{pmatrix}-3\cdot\lambda_{1}+0\cdot\lambda_{2}+1\cdot\lambda_{3}\\
   4\cdot\lambda_{1}-3\cdot\lambda_{2}+1\cdot\lambda_{3}\\
   1\cdot\lambda_{1}+2\cdot\lambda_{2}+0\cdot\lambda_{3}
   \end{pmatrix}=v,$$ which again is a linear system that you need to solve. When you find the solution $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, that'll be the the coefficients of the combination $\sum_j \lambda_j p_j$ searched for.
4. Note that the above can also be written in matrix notation like this:
   $$\begin{pmatrix}-3 & 0 & 1\\
   4 & -3 & 1\\
   1 & 2 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{1}\\
   \lambda_{2}\\
   \lambda_{3}
   \end{pmatrix}=v,$$ which explains why solving the matrix (I'd say *vector*, rather) equation $Ax=v$ gives you the coefficients of the combination :)